# Why is this GAS script taking so long to load data validation options?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I'm pulling data from a different sheet called Database. I understand that this is not a best practice, but it serves the purpose...
The code is taking long to load, considering that it has, so far, about 900 rows and it brings unique values from column 13, if values in column 1 match what's on cell B3.
Curiously, I got it running fine in other sheets, but this is setting me up:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Edit Entry');
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Database");
  var periodList = new Array();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
 if (ss.getSheetName() === "Edit Entry" && activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() == 3) {
    activeCell.offset(1, 0).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    ss.getRange("A7:L").clearContent();
  var dataRng = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getLastRow(), 15).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < dataRng.length; i++) {
    if (dataRng[i].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) != -1) {
      periodList.push(dataRng[i][12]);
    }
  }
  //This function removes duplicates from the list/array
  function removeDups(periodList) {
    var outArray = [];
    periodList.sort();
    outArray.push(periodList[0]);
    for (var n in periodList) {
      //Logger.log(outArray[outArray.length-1]+'  =  '+versionList[n]+' ?');
      if (outArray[outArray.length - 1] != periodList[n]) {
        outArray.push(periodList[n]);
      }
    }
    outArray.sort();
    return outArray;
  }
  var newPeriodList = removeDups(periodList);
    var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
    validation.setAllowInvalid(false);
    validation.requireValueInList(newPeriodList, true);
    activeCell.offset(1, 0).setDataValidation(validation.build());
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Cheers,

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet for replicating your issue, for example, when you copied the Google Spreadsheet as new Google Spreadsheet and test your script again, what result will you obtain? I thought that if the same situation occurs, the values and structure of Spreadsheet might have the reason of the issue. If no issue occurs, it might be a bug in the original Spreadsheet. But I'm not sure this leads to the direct solution of your issue, I apologize for this.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike! I've created a copy and the script is still taking about 30 sec to run. So curious! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing my proposals. From your replying, it seems that your situation might be the former in my previous comment. So in that case, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm your situation. Even when you cannot do it, please don't worry. It's no problem.

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike! As a test, I deleted data from the columns in between the ones which are compared in the first for loop and it worked! So apparently, this is what's make it lag. How would limit this for loop so it doesn't check for all vcolumns, but only the ones that matter (01first and 13th columns)? Here's a copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w0ZxRHJBKuoJ1gqjJ_HvjFMEJR1Wihq8gBbySDHsomk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your script again, it seems that in your script, `activeCell.getValue()` is used in a loop. I thought that this might be one of reasons of your issue. So how about putting `var v = activeCell.getValue();` before the line of `for (var i = 0; i < dataRng.length; i++) {` and modify `if (dataRng[i].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) != -1) {` to `if (dataRng[i].indexOf(v) != -1) {`, what result will you obtain? But, if this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: That was the problem...calling it as many times as there were rows to compare. Thank you! Are you posting an answer for me to qualify it as the solution?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And I appreciate your kind proposal. From your replying, I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your script, I noticed that `activeCell.getValue()` is used in a loop. I thought that this might be one of reasons of your issue. So in this case, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### From:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataRng.length; i++) {
  if (dataRng[i].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) != -1) {
    periodList.push(dataRng[i][12]);
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
var v = activeCell.getValue();  // Added
for (var i = 0; i < dataRng.length; i++) {
  if (dataRng[i].indexOf(v) != -1) {  // Modified
    periodList.push(dataRng[i][12]);
  }
}
```